# Not getting response from php get request

Tags: php

I have written the code given below. The first statement of `if` is working correctly, but the second one is not working. I have tried changing code, but it's not working. Even I have tried coding outside of the `if else` statement. Yet, I am not getting any response.

```
<?php
include('internet.php');
if(!empty($_GET['x'])){
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    if($x=='loadcat'){
        $cats = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category");
        $cats->execute();
        $cat = array();
        if($cats->rowCount()>0){
            while($c=$cats->fetch()){
                array_push($cat,$c['category']);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status'=>1,
            'cat'=>$cat
        ));
    }else if($x=='publisher'){
        $userid = $_POST['publisher'];
        $user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name,photo FROM users WHERE userid='$userid'");
        $user->execute();
        if($user->rowCount()==1){
            $u = $user->fetch();
            $photo = $u['photo'];
            $name = $u['name'];
            $uname = $userid;
        }else{
            $photo = '/cd_blog/img/user404.png';
            $name = '[Not Found]';
            $uname = '[Not Found]';
        }

        echo json_encode(array(
            'status'=>1,
            'photo'=>$photo,
            'name'=>$name,
            'uname'=>$uname
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is in `$x` when you display it for debugging purposes? How are you calling this code?

Comment: Why do you use the `prepare()` function, but still concatenate the `$userid` into the query string instead of passing it as a parameter?

Comment: @droopsnoot using api

Comment: @ReyadIslam I can't see how that answers either of droopsnoot's comments. What do you mean, exactly? The most likely reason for your issue would be if $x doesn't contain what you think it does. What value did you provide in the URL for it? Have you done any basic debugging to check that php has picked that up?

Comment: When you POST the `publisher` value to this url / endpoint are you posting? IE: is `GET['x']` still valid?